# jqgrid custom column row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I am using Jqgrid and I have a custom column which displays buttons in each rows. Below is the code I use with formatter option,

```
{ label: 'Custom Button', name: 'customBtn', width: 50, editable:true,
              formatter:actionButtonFormatter
},
```

Button appears fine in rows of grid(this is displayed only for certain rows), but on clicking Add and Edit buttons on nav tool bar which is at the bottom, edit using add and edit forms this custom field is getting displayed as text box even though I have given editable as true. Is there any way where I can display button for the custom column in Add and Edit form too ? Thanks   in advance.

Comment: why have you kept custom Buttom column as editable true?? shouldn't it be false?

Comment: why can't ? I have employee details in grid, in department column I have button (this is displayed only for certain rows), clicking on it which displays Jquery Dialog which displays list of available departments and I can select one. I want this to be achieved in Form Editing as well.

Comment: sorry dude, but you mentioned in your question that you have a custom column which display button in each row, didn't mention about having it with department column. Anyways, i got to work...i'll look for a solution for your question